# Angular2 nested sorting using pipes

Tags: angular, angular2-template, pipes-filters

I have a list of events wherein each event has a date property and a location property. I want to sort the list first by date and then by location name. I am able to do this using a 'sort' pipe which I can use within my template.

I was wondering if its possible to separate out the sorting into two files, one for dates and one for location names. and then chain them together.

The idea was to make the sorting pipes generic so that if someone wants to sort only by date, he/she could use only teh dateSorter pipe.

I am trying to write something like this

```
div *ngFor="let event of events | eventsOrderByDate | eventsOrderByLocationInfo">
```

But in doing so the 2nd pipe sorts the entire list again and therefore my date sorting gets messed up.

Any pointers on what I might be doing wrong here?